# Finding user object in view? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    <% @review.each do |review|%>
    <% if review.host_id == @host.id> 
       <%= @user = User.find(review.user_id) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So I'm a bit confused. I have a few things going on here. I'm doing a loop through all reviews of hosts and then checking if the stored host.id value is equal to the active @host object's id that is passed from the controller. Problem is.. Now I need get the user object from the user ID stored in the review but, I'm unsure exactly how to do it. I can't do it from the controller as all this is done in the loop. As you can see I tried to do it with the code above but, I highly doubt I did it right. Please help me out on this. Thanks.

Comment: this bad practice use sql query in views

Comment: @user =  review.user  not working ?

Comment: I'm sorry Monk Code I'm honestly still quite new to Rails but yeah, I didn't think it was. What would you recommend? And Thaha kp review.user does not hold the user object it holds the ID.

Comment: Again: why can't you do it in the controller? Can't you make loop there? Also you probably prefer to use `@user = User.find(@review.find{|r| r.host == @host}.id)`

Comment: @user3068704 not worry about it but remember. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pre-load users with loading reviews, in controller. First, you should have `belongs_to` association, like this:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # ...
end
```

then, in controller, you could use `includes`, this way:

```
@reviews = Review.includes(:user)
```

Now, for every `review` record in `@reviews` relation, to get associated user you can call `user` method, like this:

```
review.user
```

What's more, (and that's advantage of using `includes`) it doesn't fire new SQL query for every single review, so you avoid quite common [N + 1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97197/1279683).

Comment: Thank you. I never knew this is what you could do with associations. Still fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a relationship in

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

and then in view

```
review.user #gives you user
```

Answer (score 0):

Put association in Review Model

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

.
.
.
  belongs_to :user
.
.
.

end
```

After putting association you can directly call association to find user object using Review object.

review.user

But this will raise N+1 query problem, so better user include user while finding review, It will execute only two queries one for finding reviews and another for finding users.

```
@reviews = Review.includes(:user)
```